# Javascript Invalid character error in Internet Explorer but not Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

So I have an error:

> JavaScript critical error at line 216, column 35 in http://localhost:53351/Scripts/statement.form.js\n\nSCRIPT1014: Invalid character

I don't get this error in Google Chrome and only in IE
The error is coming from this line of javascript code:

```
function DownloadStatements(selectedYears, selectedMonths) { 
    window.location.href = ROOT + 
                 `Home/DownloadStatements?year=${selectedYears}&month=${selectedMonths}`;
}
```

Comment: IE does not support [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#:~:text=Template%20literals%20are%20string%20literals%20allowing%20embedded%20expressions.,strings%22%20in%20prior%20editions%20of%20the%20ES2015%20specification.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the issue is the back tick character is not valid in your version of IE.

Template literals are relatively new, and are not supported in legacy browsers

Check out this link for supported browsers https://caniuse.com/#feat=template-literals

Solutions/Workarounds:

- don't use back ticks in applications targeting legacy browsers, use single or double quotes
- bundle your application using Babel or other transpiler tool
- in addition to the first solution, you could use client side templating libraries such as mustache, to get a similar feature as a developer.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the back tick characters cannot be used prior to the implementation of ECMA script 2015. So if you're using Internet Explorer, or another old browser, you will have to use another type of quotes and classic concatenation:

```
window.location.href = ROOT + 'Home/DownloadStatements?year=' + selectedYears + 'month=' + selectedMonths;
```